# I do not see the public key and the private key to update

Tags: stellar-website, key

I received an email to update my Stellar account
but after logging in, I don't even see the public and private key, which should come out in this place to update the account

... I would like the stellar team to solve this problem ...

[image: Screenshot of upgrade request]

Answer (score 3):

That is a scam email you received. Please do not interact with it or give your secret key.

Comment: I'm aware of the scam email but this does appear to be a genuine bug with the website, I see this error when I login to https://launch.stellar.org/#/dashboard.